# Make an object available to all controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo, codeigniter-2

I am trying to make a variable (a PDO instance) available to all my controllers. In my application/core/MY_Controller.php I have:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $pdo;
}
```

Application/controllers/login.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        if(!$this->pdo instanceof PDO)
        {
            $this->load->view('login_form');
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('home');
        }
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $hostname = $this->input->post('hostname');
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname", $username, $password);

        if($this->pdo instanceof PDO)
        {
            redirect('home');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }
}
```

application/controllers/home.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'PDO should be available here but it is not:';
        print_r($this->pdo);
    }
}
```

application/views/login_form.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <?php echo form_open('login/connect'); ?>
        <label for="hostname">Hostname</label>
        <input type="text" id="hostname" name="hostname" />
        <label for="username">User name</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" id="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am testing this locally. When I go to the site address the login form is shown as expected. On submit login::connect() gets called and I know $this->pdo contains a PDO instance (if i use print_r($this->pdo in login::connect it shows 'PDO Object ( )'). But when I redirect to the Home controller $this->pdo doesn't contain the PDO instance.

What am I doing wrong? Does it have to do with my redirecting to the Home controller? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your database connectivity should be handled by your models, not your controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your PDO object should not be in your controller.

Second your problem is that the "Home" instance never created the pdo object. This is not an error with controllers, redirecting or anything, but a basic flaw in OO thinking.

```
class A {
  public $test;
}

class B extends A {
  function setTest($test) { $this->test = $test; }
}

class C extends A
{
}

$b = new B(); // create instance of B
$b->setTest("hello"); // set value in INSTANCE of B
$c = new C(); // create instance of C
echo $c->test; // get value from instance of C
```

This is basically what you are doing. You expect a value set in the instance of B to be available in the instance of C. But that is not going to work. You could have the pdo initialized in the constructor or init, but this creates a lot of pdo instances, so that is not good. You would need either a singleton or registry where you can store this and have it readily available.

and once more to repeat. pdo should not be in controller but in domain logic (so your models)